# Unwanted communication extension doesn't send network request

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods

I have unwanted communication extension for calls spam report. I configured associated domains, set endpoint in info.plist file. Anyway i have an error in logs when im trying to send something using junk/notJunk action with userInfo.

Here is my `apple-app-site-association` file

```
{"classificationreport": {"apps": ["TeamID.ExtensionBundleId"]}, "messagefilter": {"apps": ["TeamID.ExtensionBundleId"]}}
```

and here is my `.entitlements` file

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>classificationreport:myDomain.com</string>
        <string>messagefilter:myDomain.com</string>
    </array>
```

`apple-app-site-association` file is in root directory `myDomain.com/apple-app-site-association`

i don't think that problem is in my `apple-app-site-association` file cause i 200 response from

```
CONNECT app-site-association.cdn-apple.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: app-site-association.cdn-apple.com
User-Agent: swcd (unknown version) CFNetwork/1240.0.4 Darwin/20.5.0
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
```

At first a had only a `classificationreport` key, but in logs was an error

```
com.apple.IdentityLookup.MessageFilter Extension's containing app (appID <private>) unauthorized to defer requests to host <private>
```

and

```
com.apple.IdentityLookup.MessageFilter Error reporting to network: <Private>
```

I don't understand why there is a `com.apple.IdentityLookup.MessageFilter` when unwanted communication extension has `com.apple.identitylookup.classification-ui`
so i added a `messageFilter` key in associated domains, but it didn't change anything

If you have any ideas of what's going wrong i will be very grateful.

Comment: What does "I have unwanted communication extension for calls spam report" mean?

Comment: It means that i use UnwantedCommunicationExtension target to classify call as useful or spam and send this information to the server

Comment: It seems likely that there is a problem with your app bundle and your site association file. You can try installing the messages debug profile and performing a sysdiagnose to get the details of the asa files that have been fetched by your device. https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Not only extension but main app should have `classificationreport` and `messagefilter` associated domains and main app bundle id should be inside `apple-app-site-association` file

```
{
  "classificationreport": {
    "apps": [
      "TeamID.mainAppBundleID",
      "TeamID.extensionBundleID"
    ]
  },
  "messagefilter": {
    "apps": [
      "TeamID.mainAppBundleID",
      "TeamID.extensionBundleID"
    ]
  }
}
```